# Getting infinite loop on execvp()

Tags: c, bash, fork, execvp

I am learning about how fork() works and I am running into an infinite loop when calling `execvp(argh[0], argv);`

Here is my program:

```
 int main (int argc, char *argv[])
 {
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) { // error occurred 
            printf("Something went wrong!\n");
            exit(-1);
    } else if (pid == 0) { // child process 
            printf("Child process.  ");
            if(argc == 1 || argc == 0) {
                    printf("No arguments provided. Terminating child.\n");
                    exit(0);
            } else if(argc == 2) {
                    printf("One argument provided.\n");
                    execlp(argv[1], argv[1], NULL);
            } else {
                    printf("More than one argument\n");
                    execvp(argv[0], argv); // *** It's right here ***
            }
    } else { // parent process 
            printf("PARENT started with pid=%d.\n", pid);
            int status = 0;
            pid_t wait(int *status);
            printf("PARENT resumed with status code: %i.  Now terminating parent.\n", status);
            exit(0);
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

I'm trying to perform the operation (and arguments) that are passed into the function, with this code `execvp(argv[0], argv)`, but I'm getting an infinite loop when I do `./arguments ls -l`.  How should I be calling execvp?  Or should I call another method?

Thanks for any help

---Update---

I made the change suggested in an answer which was to call `execvp(argv[1], argv);` (change the arguv[0] to arguv[1]) and I now get `cannot access ls: No such file or directory` rather than an infinite loop.

Answer (score 4):

When you do `./arguments ls -l`, your code is executing `execvp("./arguments", {"./arguments", "ls", "-l"})`. Your program is forking and calling itself infinitely: you have made [fork-bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb). :)

This is because `argv[0]` is **your** executable file (i.e. *./arguments*).

You should use `argv[1]` instead, like this:

```
execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]);
```

Note you have to change both the first and the second argument.

When executed, that line will be equivalent to: `execvp("ls", {"ls", "-l"})`.

Comment: thanks for taking a look.  I made that change and now I get `cannot access ls: No such file or directory`

Comment: Did you mean `argv+1` ?

Comment: argv+1 seems to do exactly what &argv[1] does

Comment: @WeatherVane: I find `&argv[1]` more intuitive because from that expression I can easily guess that *argv* is an array without looking at type declaration.